# Linear operator as a coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is solving the equation below:
$$
 \frac{dx}{dt}=Atx+x,
$$
where $A: R^n\rightarrow R^n $ is a linear operator.
Should I consider $A$ as a constant? So the answer would be
$$
  \ln x=A(\frac{t^2}{2}+t)+c.
$$
If not, would you please help with this? any explanation or any Link to a tutorial page. Thanx.

Comment: A is indeed constant. But what you have written doesn't make sense. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, so $\ln x$ isn't defined. But the solution is still a little consistent. If you have $x' = F(t)x$ for $F$ a linear operator dependent on a parameter, then $x = \exp\left(\int_0^t F(t)dt\right) x_0$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If $A$ can be diagonalized, then you can do something like you propose.

Comment: A is said to be a linear operator, Not a matrix.